# How to extract Type III Fixed effects under the glmer procedure?

Tags: logistic, fixed-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I need to extract the Type III fixed effects for reporting in a manuscript but cannot figure out how to extract this information. Specifically, I.m requesting a hypothesis tests for the significance of each of my fixed effects. See also [SAS User Guide for detailed description on Type III fixed effects.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_a0000001477.htm) My R code is as follows:

```
 results <- glmer(R0A1~MP_Scaled*Season1+MPHW_Scaled*Season1+
                HW_Scaled*Season1+YP_Scaled*Season1+AG_Scaled*Season1+
                Shrub_Scaled*Season1+(1|ID)+(1|Site),
                data=turkey2nd,family=binomial, 
  glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
       optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

Running the same analysis in SAS, I can easily obtain the Type III fixed effects in the output. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: see `effects`, `lsmeans`, `afex` packages.  (And please define exactly what you mean by "Type III fixed effects" -- not all of us are fluent in SAS!)

Comment: PS you can probably shorten your fixed-effects formula to `Season1*(MP_Scaled+MPHW_Scaled + HW_Scaled + AG_Scaled + Shrub_Scaled + YP_Scaled)`

Comment: @BenBolker, thank you for the post. I've also revised my post to include what I meant by Type III fixed effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to use the `afex` package, i.e. something like:

```
library("afex")
set_sum_contrasts()
results <- ... ## as above
mixed(results,data=turkey2nd)
```

Comment: I tried the above code and received the following error:

Comment: (1) your error didn't make it into your comment; (2) the most useful way to get feedback is to provide a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) -- that way we don't have to go back and forth with remote debugging of whatever advice i may have given ...

Comment: sorry for the error. Please ignore my earlier comment. I re-ran the above generalized linear mixed model and could not get the model to converge despite re-scaling. I did a little investigating and determined the variance for the random effect for individual animal ID was  zero indicating that the animals were selecting for similar habitat types (not surprising for turkeys).

Comment: Therefore, I just went with a GLM approach. However, I was wondering for future reference whether the scale() function is used to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation rather than manually doing this. Thanks for again for the help!

Comment: yes, if you have continuous predictors then scaling and (especially) centering with `scale()` makes sense: see Schielzeth, Holger. “Simple Means to Improve the Interpretability of Regression Coefficients.” Methods in Ecology and Evolution 1 (2010): 103–13. doi:10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00012.x.

Comment: thanks for the reference! How would standardizing the coefficients using the scale() function affect the interpretation if you plugged the beta coefficient estimates into the formula form: exp (beta 1+ beta 2 + beta 3....+beta x)? I'm using my above model to predict habitat selection and then will use the exp() formula in ArcGIS to create a predictive map of selection where I multiply each beta to the respective habitat grid (e.g., mature pine). The issue is how the standardized betas would affect the output. Any suggestions? Thanks!